# codeigniter load a view without any html header for printing

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter, printing, codeigniter-2

php

```
function print(){
    $data=$this->session->userdata('print_data');
    $this->load->view('printer',$data);
}
```

Html (printer view)

```
<div id='printerwrapper'>
......
</div>
<style>.....</style>
<script>windows.print();</script>
```

when i view this and print it out, it print the whole page and the div is resized to become small part of page , so i checked the html of page found that ci didnt just render the view but it also added all meta tags and basic html page structure.

```
<html><head><title></title></head><body>......</body></html>
```

here is example of the page im trying to print out
[image]
all i want to print is this Div, not whole page !

is there something i should know about how to make a printable pages ?

Comment: CI will not add any of its own HTML to your views, maybe it's coming from your browser?

Comment: +1 @stef in chrome at least, there is an option to disable printing the header/footer

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can easily print a **Selected div** by **JavaScript**. Have a look the following code....

First add this JavaScript code in the head...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function printDiv(divName) {
    var printContents = document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML;
    var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;
    document.body.innerHTML = printContents;
    window.print();
    document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
}
</script>
```

and then the view page are as follows...

```
<div id="printableArea">
       Your Content here.....
</div>


<input type="button" onclick="printDiv('printableArea')" value="Print Invoice" />
```

When you click the Print Invoice Button. Then it will print out with the selected DIV id **Printablearea**

Try this. Hope it will work. Best of luck.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's the browser's goal to make a print look similar to the way it looks on-screen, unless it's told otherwise. With that said, maybe you should consider just using a CSS stylesheet specifically for printing by using `@media print`. I went and [found an article](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/24/how-to-set-up-a-print-style-sheet/) for you that I remember seeing quite some time ago in regards to print media queries.

It really depends on your objective though. If you want the on-screen version to look like it does now, but the print version to look different, I think this is the way to go. If it doesn't matter how it looks on-screen, maybe you could get rid of your printerwrapper altogether and just float things left and right.